# Laravel 10 - Submit Form after Login trough Auth Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I want to submit a form in Laravel, the controller and route are secured with Auth Middleware. Now the user is redirected to the login and then back to the form, but without the old values. Is it possible that Laravel automatically sends the POST request after the login was successful or the redirection to the form contains the old values.

I have so far tried rewriting the auth middleware and caching the data in a session and then reading it out and removing it when it is sent. However, I find the solution quite insecure and would like to know a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: How do you redirect the user back to the form after he logs in?

Comment: you should put the GET route for loading that page and form inside auth middleware as well so the user has to login before even filling out the form. That would be the best solution honestly.